# How to set php sessions?

Tags: php

How would I set a php session?
Here's my code , yet it should work when I require it on the logged in page it just redirects me to the login page (its not set)

```
<?php
   $_SESSION['logged_in']==1;
   header('Location: loggedin.php');
?>
```

Comment: `session_start()` at the top!

Answer (score 0):

Use `=` to assign not `==`. Double equal is used to compare. Also use `session_start();` top of your code. Example:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
header('Location: loggedin.php');
```

Comment: And explanation would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

You use double equal to sign (==) while comparing 2 quantities. You've to use 1 equal sign to assign value.

It should be:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['logged_in']=1;
   header('Location: loggedin.php');
?>
```